# How to prove that |sin(n!)| = Theta(1)?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I had such an equation on Algorithms and Data Structures subject. It looks very obvious but how exactly I can prove it?

Even on graph we can see that |sin(n!)| does not go above 1 and below 0.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notation Theta(1). You mean you need to prove |sin(n!)| is a [bounded function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Technically it's not *ϴ(1)* because *sin(n)* can be *0* (and *sin(n!)* can go arbitrarily close to zero), so it is not bounded below by a positive constant.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of *|sin(n)|* is *O(1)*:

We have two functions:

- *f(n) = |(sin(n!)|*
- *g(n) = 1*

And we have to proof that for every *n > 0* this statement is correct: *f(n) <= g(n)*
Let's use induction for such case:
*Base* - For *n = 1*, *f(1) ~= 0.8* and *g(1)=1* 
*Induction* - Suppose that *f(n) <= g(n)* for *n = 1, 2, 3, ...k*. Now let's show that for *k+1* the *f(k+1) <= g(k+1)* is valid also.

- n! range is from 1 to inifinity
- *sin(x)* by definition can be *[-1, 1]*, so *sin(n!)* has same range as well.
- *|sin(n!)|* scopes it to be *[0, 1]*
- Whatever *k* was *f(k+1)* still will be in range of *[0, 1]*, therefore *f(k+1) <= g(k+1)*, therefore our statement is correct for any *k*.

As it was mentioned by @Berthur in comments, we have to proof as well that *|sin(n)|* has a lower positive non-zero bound. We can't show that, because *|sin(n)|* can have arbitrary close to zero values.

Comment: "sin(x) by definition can be [-1, 1], so sin(n!) has same range as well. |sin(n!)| scopes it to be [0, 1]." Isn't that proof enough? I see no purpose in using induction here.

Comment: I think so, just wanted to make it more formal.

Comment: This proves only the upper bound, so *|sin(n!)| = O(1)*, not the lower bound also required for *|sin(n!)| = ϴ(1)*.

Comment: @Berthur, you're right, this is valid only for upper bound, I'll update my answer to reflect that.